# How to create a Generic[T] where T is 'X or subclasses of X'

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I would like to have a container that can contain the type of T where T denotes type X or subclasses of X. Using `TypeVar("T", bound=X)` will only allow for subclasses of X, which seems to be the intended use case.

I figured two things:

1. Converting X to a base class, from which I would subclass with empty body. After that I could use `TypeVar` bound to X, while doing work with the subclassed type.
2. I could do `T | X` where `T` is bound to X.

However, neither of these feels like the correct way to do it. I also read about protocols, however I'm not sure it is the right way either.

What am I looking for?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you need here, but it's pretty likely that `TypeVar("T", bound=X)` is already it. `T` is allowed to be `X`; it doesn't have to be a strict subclass of `X`.

Comment: (The other primary possibility is that all you need is `X`, and the type variable is entirely unnecessary.)

Comment: Say I have method arg that expects T, when I pass/assign an instance of X to it, mypy will complain that types do not match (expected T, given X), just typing X won't work since I want my container to contain subclasses of X as well

Comment: That sounds like you should just be using `X`, with no type variable, then.

Comment: Using `X` directly doesn't stop your container from holding subclass instances. A `list[dict]` can hold instances of `collections.Counter` and other `dict` subclasses, for example.

Comment: I did not know that, alright. Can you tell me, then,  what is one of the proper use cases for the thing I tried, i.e., something like Generic[T].

Comment: If you want to write your own container class, and be able to declare "this instance of my container class is a `Container[XSubclass1]`, so it can't hold `XSubclass2` instances", you'd use a type variable.

Comment: @user2357112 This statement about `list[dict]` is incorrect. Generic types in Python are _invariant_ in all type variables by default. See [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg: Generics are invariant by default, but you're misinterpreting what invariance means. Invariance means that a `list[collections.Counter]` isn't a `list[dict]`, even though it's a list whose elements are all dicts. It does *not* mean that a `list[dict]` can't hold `collections.Counter` instances.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right, I mistook what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class `X` and you want to have some custom container that can hold instances of `X` or of any subclass of `X`, you need to

1. Define a type variable (say `T`) with the `bound=X` and
2. Subclass `Generic[T]` for your container.

Here is an example:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="X")  # X or subclass of X


class X:
    pass


class SubX(X):
    pass


class MyContainer(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, items: Iterable[T]) -> None:
        self.items = items

    def get_first(self) -> T:
        """This is just to for demonstration purposes."""
        return next(iter(self.items))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    container1 = MyContainer([X(), X(), X()])
    container2 = MyContainer([SubX(), SubX(), SubX()])
    container3 = MyContainer([X(), SubX()])
    container4 = MyContainer([1, 2, 3])  # wrong
```

The last line will cause a `type-var` error by `mypy` with the following statement:

```
error: Value of type variable "T" of "MyContainer" cannot be "int"
```

Comment: This kind of works, but judging by the conversation in the comments, its behavior probably isn't quite what the questioner is looking for. For example, `container2` is deduced as `MyContainer[SubX]`, and (if `MyContainer` actually had a way to add elements) you wouldn't be able to add objects of type `X` to `container2`.

Comment: From the conversation in the comments, it sounds like the questioner doesn't really need to write a generic class at all. Removing the `Generic[T]` and just having `__init__` take `Iterable[X]` and `get_first` return `X` seems more in line with what the questioner is looking for.